# CSS background-image gradient in :root

Tags: css, css-selectors, background-image, css-variables

I have a code that obviously doesn't work. It is a gradient after the body element. Gradient was working before I decided to move colors to :root. And here is this problematic code:

```css
:root {
--primary: #222;
--primary-rgb: 31, 31, 31;
--color-888: #888;
--color-888-rgb: 136, 136, 136;
--color-1f1: #1f1f1f;
--color-white-button: #fff;
--color-b8b: #b8b8b8;
--color-f21: #F23D3F;
--pre-bg-rgb: 31, 31, 31;
--scrollbar-hover: #4a4a4a;
--scrollbar-active: #383838;
--fade-rgb: 34, 34, 34;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary: #fff;
  --primary-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --color-888: #000;
--color-888-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --color-1f1: #ccc;
  --color-white-button: #000;
--color-b8b: #d4d4d4;
--color-f21: #f52a2c;
--pre-bg-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
--scrollbar-hover: #363636;
--scrollbar-active: #454545;
--fade-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Here's a link to the demo: https://codepen.io/MAJO-SEARCH/project/editor/XEWoVE

Comment: Try reading here about `content`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content I'm just surprised if `body` have pseudo-elements, and why can't you just use background-image on the body tag?

Comment: Body have custom elements. The code
`css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
` 
Is working...

Comment: share the code where you are adding the colors to root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old syntax that is no more needed and doesn't work with CSS variable.

Simply do like below. Gradient is now supported everywhere and no need vendor prefixes.

```css
  :root {
  --primary: #222;
  --primary-rgb: 31, 31, 31;
  --color-888: #888;
  --color-888-rgb: 136, 136, 136;
  --color-1f1: #1f1f1f;
  --color-white-button: #fff;
  --color-b8b: #b8b8b8;
  --color-f21: #F23D3F;
  --pre-bg-rgb: 31, 31, 31;
  --scrollbar-hover: #4a4a4a;
  --scrollbar-active: #383838;
  --fade-rgb: 34, 34, 34;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary: #fff;
  --primary-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --color-888: #000;
  --color-888-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --color-1f1: #ccc;
  --color-white-button: #000;
  --color-b8b: #d4d4d4;
  --color-f21: #f52a2c;
  --pre-bg-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --scrollbar-hover: #363636;
  --scrollbar-active: #454545;
  --fade-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 0) 0%, rgba(var(--primary-rgb), 1) 100%);
```